# How-to Keep Projects Structure with TFS Team Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've a Solution structure as below :

Solution 1 (Solution1.sln)

- Project 1
- Project 2
- Project 3

I created a Team Build definition working with Solution1.sln.
My problem is that compiled binaries are stored into a single flat output folder : BuildName\Release

But I want to keep my project structure :

BuildName\Project 1\Release

BuildName\Project 2\Release

BuildName\Project 3\Release

Answer (score 3):

See [Preserving Output Directory Structures in Orcas Team Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/07/preserving-output-directory-structures-in-orcas-team-build.aspx). It's pretty irritating that this is neccesary, and it's a per-project tweak, but it can be made to work.

Answer (score 2):

The default for Team Build is as you've seen - binaries in one folder, web sites each in a folder structure of their own; one per configuration being built. If you're just getting started with TFS, I suggest you try to use the default. You're more familiar with separate folders, but almost everything you read about Team Build will use a single output folder.

Other than familiarity, is there a reason you want separate folders?

Comment: +1 Separate folders means LOTS of duplication if your projects depend on each other.

Comment: Deployment is really the issue that is requiring multiple output folders. Each executable project only needs a subset of the infrastructure projects.

Comment: @Sean: I would recommend that each Team Build should only build a single set of deployable artifacts. If, for instance, you have multiple desktop executables, each of which only needs a subset of the infrastructure, and if you deploy each individually, then you need multiple Team Builds. If, on the other hand, you can have a single installer that installs only the necessary files for each, then you would only want one team build.